# Code in upper .htacces file gets ignored by code in other .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two .htaccess files on my server.

`/public_html/.htaccess` contains some commands to e.g. redirect everything to `https://www.` and always add a trailing slash to the url.

`/public_html/test_path/.htaccess` contains the following code:

```
RewriteEngine ON

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ ?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This is to rewrite e.g. `https://www.example.com/test_path?id=123` to `https://www.example.com/test_path/123`.

For some reason, the code in `/public_html/test_path/.htaccess` prevents the code in `/public_html/.htaccess` to get executed.

Means, the rewrite rule in `/public_html/test_path/.htaccess` is working, but the code in `/public_html/.htaccess` doesn't get respected any more, e.g. there's no redirection to `https://www.` any more.

Why does the code in `/public_html/test_path/.htaccess` prevent the code in `/public_html/.htaccess` to also get executed?

Comment: Add the content of the top level file to your question too. The files are read from the lowest level directory to the highest level. Unless there are conflicting rules both will be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For some reason, the code in `/public_html/test_path/.htaccess` prevents the code in `/public_html/.htaccess` to get executed.

This is by design. If current directory has a .htaccess with `RewriteEngine On` then it overrides parent .htaccess directives.

If you want parent .htaccess rules to be applied before then use [`RewriteOptions` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions):

```
RewriteOptions InheritBefore
```

Before `RewriteEngine On` line.

Comment: Thanks, that works, but I don't really understand. Just removing `RewriteEngine On` won't fix it, will it?

Comment: If you remove `RewriteEngine On` then you will lose ability to have localized rules in `/test_path/` directory. Please check documentation link I have provided in my answer.

Comment: If I keep the code in `/public_html/test_path/.htaccess` and only remove `RewriteEngine On` nothing changes. Seems like `RewriteEngine On` doesn't have any affect, does it?

Comment: Yes that's right even if you remove `RewriteEngine On`, rules in the `test_path/.htaccess` would still work however `RewriteOptions InheritBefore` would still be required if you want parent .htaccess rules to execute before current set of rules.